# Cockpit CMS reordering Repeater field

Tags: php, content-management-system, cockpit-cms

I have a `repeater` of `set` fields in my Collection in Cockpit CMS.

Options is:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "set",
      "label": "Some Block",
      "options": {
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "title",
            "type": "text"
          },
          {
            "name": "picture",
            "type": "image"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How to use `display` option in `repeater` for display `title` field with re-ordering mode? If it's possible.

The cockpit docs are not sufficiently informative, and it [says](https://getcockpit.com/documentation/reference/fieldtypes):

```
"display": null // display value on re-order
```

And how to use this option in other cases, except `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I found the solution.

Option `display` can be a part of `options` of `set` field:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "set",
      "label": "Some Block",
      "options": {
        "display": "title", // it must be placed here
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "title",
            "type": "text"
          },
          {...}
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```